# Validate texbox by comparing select options to textbox contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

So I have an add contacts page where I need to popup an error message or mark input as invalid if they attempt to enter an already existing contact name.

There will likely be a select populated with the options. However I am not sure how to compare the option values of the select to the texbox....

I need to check that the text in the contact textbox does not exist in any of the select options.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ContactsDropdown" 
  runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnContactChanged" 
 </asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:TextBox ID="Contact" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly ,don't forget to add  `ClientIDMode="Static"` both to `ContactsDropdown` and `Contact` controls ,so as you can get the select element with jquery.More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx).

Then you can use this simple condition:

```
var exists= $("#ContactsDropdown option[value='"+ $("#Contact").val()+"']").length > 0;
if (exists)
{
alert("Error - > Exists!")
//or do something 
}
else{
//do something else
}
```

Hope it helps!